# HTTPS from Adobe Air application on Ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, air, https, adobe

I'm working on Adobe Air application for IPad (ios 6.0.1) which will authenticate user based on its certificate.

I have trusted certificate of the client in the IPad, i have trusted certificate of the server in the IPad, when I open URL address of server in Safari certificate based authentication is successfull... when I tried the same using HTTPService or even StageWebView it doesn't work!

When I call stageWebView.loadUrl(HTTPS_URL_OF_THE_SERVER_WHICH_WORKS_IN_SAFARI) I'm getting error - "The server did not accept the certificate. errorID=3228"

In the server log there is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandShakeException: null cert chain.

I'm using IPad 2 with iOS 6.0.1.

Simon: Could you please be more specific with your solution?

You have to accept the certificate on every new Startup of the app.

on Ipad, application is not asking me to accept any certificate (is it configuration problem??)
You first call (over the stageWebView) will not work. Because this calls the dialog and you cant dispatch the dialog input. So you have to handle it by yourself that you make your HTTPS request after that dialog.

I haven't seen any dialog to choose certificate not even in Safari.